# Can I lazyload Tables generated with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, lazy-loading

I have a lot tables generated vertically with PHP and on request takes a lot time to be rendered. Is there any way to lazy load tables?

Comment: the problem is like I'm generating with php some calculations and render those in tables on data what what I fetched from database. At this time I have like 62 tables. The request takes long because of rendering. If there is  an async workaround for this, yes I would go with

Comment: Can you provide some code as how you are pulling the data from your database? You tagged Javascript, have you attempted any Javascript code? To add to what @deroccha said, you still have to consider it is a server-side process, and the load-time can be better decreased on the database query.

Comment: thanks for feedback I will update my post with codes

Answer (score 0):

You could expose the php which builds the tables as an API, and make async ajax requests on page load to get the table markup. That way your page would finish rendering faster and then as and when the tables are ready, you can have a response handler function which attaches the returned markup to the page. You could also show a little loading animation until the request return, if that was important.